# Un adjectif pour "aux couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel"

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, synonymes

Je cherche un adjectif imagé pour susciter l'évocation mentale qu'un objet (voire un [poney](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Rainbow_Dash)) est aux couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel. J'ai pensé à irisé, mais c'est à la fois moins spécifique, et d'un niveau de vocabulaire un peu technique qui ne parle pas à tout le monde de façon obvie.

Comment: Pourquoi *irisé* serait-il « moins spécifique » ? C'est exactement le terme que tu cherches.

Comment: @Gilles Irisé veut dire exactement ça, mais ce n'est pas connu de tout le monde. Je ne savais pas moi-même avant de regarder dans un dictionnaire, je pensais que c'était comme les bulles de savon ou le dos des scarabées, des couleurs qui changent en fonction de l'angle duquel on les voit.

Comment: A part *irisé* il y a *arc-en-ciel* utilisé comme adjectif. "Ce poney a une queue arc-en-ciel". Je ne pense pas qu'il existe un autre adjectif.

Answer (score 1):

Les mots qui me viendraient à l'esprit seraient

> Bigarré
>
> Multicolore

Il y a effectivement irisé ou iridescent mais ce sont des termes plus techniques.

Comment: Je crois qu'il n'y aura rien de mieux qu'*irisé*, qui veut exactement dire "des couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel". Aucun des autres mots que tu as cités ne veut exactement dire cela.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Simon - Iris était précisément la déesse grecque dont les pas laissaient des traces aux couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel. On ne pourra pas faire mieux pour la précision. "_bigarré_" et "_multcolore_" ne sont pas aussi précis.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi:

> polychromatique

qui est plus lié à la lumière.

Comment: Même commentaire que ci-dessus à propos d'_irisé_.

Comment: J'ai bien précisé que ma réponse concerne plus la lumière que la couleur.